# Where clause SQLite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i am developing an android app, where i need to pick all the columns of a row from the database table based on the keyid of that row. I have tried various solutions , but didnt work.

here is what i have tried,

```
               String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_COLOURS;
               Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

i need to pick all the columns of the particular row in TABLE_COLOURS, how can i do it.Please help, thanks!

Comment: what is error in this.??

Comment: define "didn't work". select * *does* select all columns in a table. if you base you query on a keyid, you should consider using a where clause with that column name and its desired value. If you have no idea what I am saying, start by any tutorial on SQL.

Comment: select * from TABLE_COLOURS where keyid = "1";   i want this in SQLite syntax.please help

Comment: SQLite speaks standard SQL. Is `keyid` really a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help?

```
Cursor dbCursor = db.query(TABLE_COLOURS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
String[] columnNames = dbCursor.getColumnNames();
```

What you are querying for are the values from table, not its schema info.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code

```
     String sql="select * from TABLE_COLOURS where id=id";
     Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Comment: tried it, its giving an error,, please check the following link http://txtup.co/gWkZW

Comment: The error showing that your table is not properly created. first create your table and then try with this code.